# How to convert video for web with ffmpeg

Tags: web, video, ffmpeg, html5-video

I am trying to rescale, subclip and convert video for web (html5 video tag). Target browsers : Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Ya Browser.

I am using command like that (changing some params)

`ffmpeg -i C.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -t 10 -vf scale=312x104 -vcodec libx264  -strict -2 -movflags faststart  -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v high -level 3 -r 25 -an -sn -dn  d.mp4 -y`

But every time video is not playing in some browser.

I would like to find some way to do that task fast (that's why I am using ffmpeg) and stable (so that any video passed would give me a valid video for all browsers)

I also tried to play with setsar, setdar params, but still no success

Comment: Which browsers are failing? What are the error messages printed on the non-playing browsers' dev console? Can you play the video on non-browser video players?

Comment: I don't know much about the subject, but you may try VP8 codec with WebM container: `ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -t 10 -vf scale=312x104 -vcodec vp8 -pix_fmt yuv420p d.webm -y`. You may also try more standard size like 320x240 (multiple of 16 in each axis).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I guess I found smth suitable for my case

```
Ffmpeg -i C.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -t 10 -vf scale=dstw=312:dsth=104:flags=accurate_rnd,setdar=3/1 -vcodec libx264  -level 21 -refs 2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v high -level 3.1 -color_primaries 1 -color_trc 1 -colorspace 1 -movflags +faststart -r 30 -an -sn -dn d.mp4
```